# 3D Map for website

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am trying to create a 3D map on a web page. Google Maps and Open Street Maps provide an API for using 2D maps. Are there any APIs available for 3D maps?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a recommendation engine.

Comment: Google maps has the 45-degree aerial view and there's the Google earth library too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at [WebGL Earth](https://sites.google.com/site/webglearth/), an open source project based on WebGL. [Here's a demo](http://data.webglearth.com/examples/custommap.html).

Here are other links which may be of interest to you:

- [Mapbox GL JS](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-buildings/)
- [Tangram](https://mapzen.com/products/tangram/), Open-Source OpenGL Maps
- ArcGIS Web API support [3D maps](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/get-started-sceneview/index.html).
- [wrld.js](https://www.wrld3d.com/wrld.js/latest/docs/api/), also see on [GitHub](https://github.com/wrld3d/wrld.js/tree/master).
- [cesium.js](https://cesiumjs.org), on [GitHub as well](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium).
- [see this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12859/what-are-my-options-for-3d-web-maps) with other suggestions as well!

**Edit** (08/2017): removed dead links (thanks @Pang!), added newer ones.

Comment: Some of the links in this answer are dead.